# Pass variables in calling javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

I wanna pass in some variables to my functions like `int`, `string`, and etc. I'm a C# developer and is very new in JS.

In C# we normally call a function with:

```cs
function computeGrade(int grade)
{
...
}

computeGrade(90);
```

I understand that js uses `var` that can either be a string, int, etc.
However when I try:

```
function ComputeGrade(var grade)
{
...
}
```

it gives me an error that it failed to initialize the function.

Forgive me for being too naive with js.
Thanks a ton!

Comment: In JavaScript, you don't specify the type of the parameter. Try this -> function ComputeGrade(grade) { ... }. This enables you to pass anything as the 'grade' parameter (strings, numbers, functions, etc).

Comment: @John edited it :) thanks a lot. And sorry for those unnecessary tags...

Comment: Thank you for your edit :-) On a related topic, it might be of interest to you that as of ECMAScript6 you can use [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var). There is a slight difference between `var` and `let`, but `let` behaves more like C# variables do with regards to scoping. Personally, I'd argue that `let` is a better way to go these days.

Comment: @John I've heard `let` too but was quite unsure on whether what's the main difference between the two. Thanks for the heads up! :) I'll try utilizing `let`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In js variables are just untyped name bindings. So you don't need to tell what a variable is capable of storing. Actually It just refers to any type of value.

```
function ComputeGrade(grade)
{
...
}
```

So here, grade is just a name binding. It does not matter what kind of value you pass this function. It will bind to grade variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `var` for declaring local variables. For function arguments just use the param name without `var`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This actually clarified it :D